# Как создать конструктор который копирует значения для класса наследника - Java

Tags: java

у меня есть класс `Kwadrat` который имеет копирующий конструктор `public Kwadrat(Kwadrat kwadrat)`, и есть класс наследник `Prostokat`, и я не понимаю как сделать для него тоже копирующий конструктор, что бы там был только параметр обьект класса `Prostokat`.
То есть не понимаю как мне достучатсья до переменной с надкласса.

```
public class Kwadrat {
    private int dlugosc;

    public Kwadrat() {
        this.dlugosc = 1;
    }

    public Kwadrat(int dlugosc) {
        this.dlugosc = dlugosc;
    }

    public Kwadrat(Kwadrat kwadrat) {
        this.dlugosc = kwadrat.dlugosc;
    }

    public int zwrocDlugosc() {
        return dlugosc;
    }
}
```

```
public class Prostokat extends Kwadrat{
    private int szerokosc;

    public Prostokat() {
        super();
        this.szerokosc = 1;
    }

    public Prostokat(int dlugosc, int szerokosc) {
        super(dlugosc);
        this.szerokosc = szerokosc;
    }

    public Prostokat(Prostokat prostokat) { // здесь в параметрах я все правильно указал
        // а здесь видим что я могу только установить ширину прямоугольника, 
        // а как достучаться к высоте через надкласс, не понимаю       
        this.szerokosc = prostokat.szerokosc;
    }

    public int zwrocSzerokosc() {
        return szerokosc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Prostokat(Prostokat prostokat) {
    super(prostokat); // Если не вызвать super явно, то будет вызван super без параметров
    szerokosc = prostokat.szerokosc;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но я задал вопрос на русской версии сайта, зачем английские комментарии?

Comment: @kaban.of Because I don't have the Russian keyboard and don't want to open the translit tab. If you don't like it, don't look at my answer.

Comment: o так Вы из Англии

Comment: @kaban.of Yes, because England is the only country where they speak English.

Comment: Fixed it for you.